# Some .NET 4.0 Classes in PowerShell do not seem to work

Tags: .net, powershell

I am creating a powershell script that uses some `System.Diagnostics.Process` and `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` classes.

These classes work completely fine like this:

```
$processInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

$processInfo.FileName = "dism.exe"
$processInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$processInfo.Arguments = "/Apply-Image /ImageFile:C:\images\Win864_SL-IN-837.wim /ApplyDir:D:\ /Index:1"

$process = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $processInfo
```

However, I also want to use a System.IO.StreamReader class but when I try the EXACT same thing with like this:

```
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader
```

or like this

```
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $process.FileName
```

I get the error:

```
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.IO.StreamReader.
At C:\Users\a-mahint\Documents\Testing\inter.ps1:17 char:21
+ $stream = new-object <<<<  System.IO.StreamReader
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I have been trying to figure this out for half an hour... what is going on? both Classes are part of .NET 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) doesn't have a no-arg constructor, and you haven't supplied any arguments.

Try it in C#. You'll get

> 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments

Instead, try

```
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader "foo.txt"
```

where `foo.txt` is an existing file.

Note that it doesn't have a constructor with a parameter of type `ProcessStartInfo` either, which is why passing `$process.StartInfo` didn't work. Instead, try passing `$processInfo.FileName`.

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, I meant to say I passed in `$process.StandardOutput` to the constructor which is  StreamReader type and it accepts a Stream type. So would that not work still or can I just explicitly cast it?

Comment: StreamReader does not descend from Stream. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

Comment: Matt what you are doing should work fine. The likely reason you're having issues is StandardOutput is null if you do not set the boolean to enable RedirectStandardOutput on the Process first  I think you also need to set UseShellExecute to false. You may also need to call .Start() on the Process before the StandardOutput field is populated (as there is no Stream before the process creates one).